# Solving a differential equation with an implicit function in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a differential equation in Mathematica using NDsolve, the differential equation is given by:

$y(t)''+3H(t)y(t)'+\frac{\partial V(u(y))}{\partial y}=0$

where $H(t)$ is given by:

$H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}a}\sqrt{(y(t)'^2+V(u(y)))}$

The problem is that the potential $V(u(y))=\frac{u^4}{(1+bu^2/a^2)^2}$ doesn't depend explicitly on $y$, it depends on $u$, an the relation between $y(u)$ is given by (and the code that I have, where $yr=y(u)$):

```
yr[y_] := a*Sqrt[(1 + 6 b)/b]*ArcSinh[(Sqrt[b (1 + 6 b)] u[y])/a] - Sqrt[6]*a*ArcTanh[(Sqrt[6]*b*u[y])/Sqrt[a^2 + b (1 + 6 b) u[y]^2]] 

V[y_] := u[y]^4/(1 + (b*u[y]^2)/a^2)^2;
H[t_] = Sqrt[1/(3 a^2) (1/2 y'[t]^2 + V[y])];
eom[t_] = 
Simplify[y''[t] + 3 H[t]*y'[t] + D[V[y], u[y]]*(D[yr[y], u[y]])^-1, a^2 + b*y[t]^2 > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0] // Numerator
a = 10^18;
b = 10^4;
solution = 
NDSolve[{eom[t] == 0, y[0] == 100*a, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, Subscript[t, initial], Subscript[t, final]}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> Automatic]
```

So the problem comes precisely here, I can not inverse the previous relation $u(y)$ (if it would be the case, then I can introduce this in the potential function $V$ to get $V(y)$ and the differential equation is easily solved), so how can be done to solve the differential equation in terms of the variable $y(t)$?

Also I don't know exactly how define a variable in terms of others to be solved in NDSolve, since actually I have $u(y(t))$.

I put the following numerical conditions: $a=10^{18}$, $b=10^4$, $y(t=0)=100*a$ and $y(t=0)'=0$

**Comment:**

Maybe can be useful to take into account the chain rule for the potential function $V(u(y))$:

$\frac{\partial V(u(y))}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial V(u(y))}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial V(u(y))}{\partial u} * f(h)$

But still this functions depends on $u$ not in $y$

Comment: You should share all the code defining the equations in [formatted form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it easier for us to try a workable solution. Please [edit] your question.  If  you write an [excellent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) it will inspire great answers.

Comment: You are right sorry, I have put my code, but I don't see exactly how can be defined the different functions, i.e, in terms of u,y,t...

Comment: What is the equation defining $u(y)$?  `y == yr[y]`, maybe?

Comment: yes exactly, I have editted

Comment: With the values you are using for `a` and `b`, if you plot `y` vs `u`, you will see that over a very large range that essentially `u[y] = y` which vastly simplifies the problem.  If those values are not typical, you can still convert all your equations to u[t] and try to NDSolve them that way.

Comment: @BillWatts this doens't make sense. The relation of y(u) is lineal for some range, but not for all the range of values, so you can not solve the dif. equation doing y=u. Also I want to solve y(t) and not u(t)

Comment: See the `NDSolve ` documentation for differential-algebraic equations, which you appear to have here.

Comment: 'Subscript[t, initial], Subscript[t, final]` are undefined.  Please provide.  Also, it is a good idea not to use `Subscript` except for display purposes.

Comment: I urge you to rescale your equations to eliminate the large numbers `a` and `b`.

Comment: If you plot yr with u from -5000000 to 5000000, its still linear with the values for a and b you are using.  I quit checking after that, but it is probably linear to machine precision for  all your y values.

Comment: 5000000 = 5*10^6, my initial condition is for 10^18, at this range of values for sure is not lineal, you can check by yourself